# What does "Please put forward the code that you are happy to be deployed to production system" mean?

Tags: deployment, production

"Please put forward the code that you are happy to be deployed to the production system."

I read the above sentence in a coding assessment. Could anyone please explain what it means?

Comment: What precisely do you not understand? This seems more like an English comprehension issue than a programming problem.

Comment: That's true. Just want to confirm whether it means I have to develop an application with UI so that it can be a proper website-like application.  Right now, what I did is a console application.

Comment: You can't conclude either way from that sentence, it tells you nothing about the requirements for the code.

Comment: May I ask what a production system is? Is it equivalent to the system like Heroku or AWS?

Comment: It could be. It's whatever system actually makes your code available to end users. You should really ask these clarifying questions to whoever actually has information about the task you're working on.